# box2Dweb change body color

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, box2d

I want to create colorful ropes so I have followed some tutorial and joined many boxes to create ropes but now the colors does not work here anymore.

I am using this to make it colorful but it failed.

```
body_def.userData='user_data' : {'fill_color' : 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)' , 'border_color' : '#7FE57F' }
```

Full code: http://jsfiddle.net/sadaf2605/vVaCK/

Can anyone help me a little bit with sample code?

Comment: I don't suppose you can have colors in debug draw mode. Its not your final output (which will have colors that you define). Debug Draw mode is used to check the interaction between bodies

Comment: So there is other way to do that? :/ Can you please show me a sample?

Comment: You can check out this post for some ideas and the previous posts also have some links to other references: http://aniruddhaloya.blogspot.com/2013/04/box2d-javascript-part-3.html

Comment: In short, you'll have to write a draw function that will take all your box2d bodies and render them onscreen as per your desired colors/ images